# How do you change the background color of your HTML document using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I've tried many different examples, but none seem to work. :(. Please find the code snippet below.

```
var element = document.getElementById("time");
element.style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000";
```

The code above didn't work for me and I have no idea why.

Please help!

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me. https://jsfiddle.net/pd9vthkc/

Comment: Maybe you are trying to execute the `javascript` before the DOM is ready/loaded which will display a error message in the browser console of **undefined**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the HTML tag with `document.documentElement` to apply styles to.

```js
document.documentElement.style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000";
```

You can also get the `body` tag with `document.body` to apply styles to.

```js
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000";
```

Comment: Why of the `<body>` when the question asks for `<html>`?

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! unfortunately it just won't change the color still for some reason. Wish I knew what I was doing wrong

Comment: @ErichBuelow Could you please put your code in a JSFiddle for me?